# Partial derivitives of second order

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, partial-derivative

Let $f(x, y)$ is a function which has continuous partial derivitives of order two.
Prove that the two statements below are equivalent:

1. for every $(x, y) \in R^2$ it is true that $f^{''}_{xx}=f^{''}_{yy}$
2. There exist functions of one varible ϕ(t), ψ(t), which are defined and possess continuous derivitives in $\mathbb{R}$, such that:
   $f(x, y) = ϕ(y + x) + ψ(y − x)$.

I think that if it was about the first derivitive I will use the Finite-increments formula to get these two functions of one varible. However, having to tackle second derivitives I am unable to continuone further.

To show my work here:

If we consider $\delta=f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2)-f(a_1,a_2)=f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2)-f(a_1,a_2)+f(a_1,a_2+h_2)-f(a_1,a_2+h_2)$.
We apply the Finite incr.formula:
we get the functions:
$\varphi_1(t)=f(t,a_2+h_2)$ and $\varphi_2(t)=f(a_1,t)$
Where $(h_1,h_2) \rightarrow(0,0)$ and $(a_1,a_2)$ is an arbitrary point.
So when we combine those two new functions we get that $\delta=f'x(\alpha_1,a_2+h_2)h_1+f'y(a_1,\alpha_2)h_2$ for $\alpha1 \in [a_1,a_1+h_1]$ nad the same for $\alpha_2$.

Any ideas how to use this idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the question into the differential equation
$$\partial_{xx}f-\partial_{yy}f=0.$$
This is the wave equation and the functions $f(x+y)=\phi(x+y)+\psi(x-y)$ are the well-known d'Alambert solutions. There are many ways to show this. For one, one starts with the change of the variables $(x,y)$ to $(\xi,\eta)$, where $x=\xi+\eta$, $y=\xi-\eta$ and show that the equation is equavalent to solve $\partial_{\xi}\partial_{\eta}g=0$, which is easy to integrate.